# Call Graph API from SharePoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, spfx

I need to call Graph API from spfx webpart.

Previously we used the following method:

```
import { MSGraphClient } from '@microsoft/sp-client-preview';
```

But later we got to know that MSGraphClient is depreciated now in sp-client-preview.

I checked the following method which is mentioned in Microsoft docs also.

```
import { MSGraphClient } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
```

But it is giving an error as following:

> Module '"d:/O365/upload-onedrive/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-http/dist/index-internal"' has no exported member 'MSGraphClient'

SPFx version we are using now is 1.6

Is there any way call Graph API from spfx now?

Answer (score 2):

Of course we can use Graph in SPFx.

Graph+adal+SPFx steps:

1. Create an application in [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/). Click the manifest, then change "**oauth2AllowImplicitFlow**" value to true
2. Go to **Settings->Required Permissions->ADD->Select an API->Microsoft Graph**, select the permission and then **Grant Permissions**.
3. Build HelloWorld SPFx project : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part
4. Add and IAdalConfig.ts  and WebPartAuthenticationContext.js patch files

   **Tips: If you have no adal module in node_modules/@types folder, you'd better manually install the module using the command : npm install @types/adal@1.0.29**
5. Add the following code to **render()**

   ```
     // Make an AJAX request to the Graph API and print the response as JSON.
     var getToken;

     var getCurrentUser = function (access_token) {
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.open('GET', 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', true);
       xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token);

       xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

         if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {

           // Do something with the response

           getToken=JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText), null, '  ');
           console.log('get Graph APi information=='+getToken);
         } else {
           // TODO: Do something with the error (or non-200 responses)
         //  console.log(' error');
         }
       };
       xhr.send();
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try it out soon!

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no reason to create any applications in the Azure side, it's all automatic and taken care of by SharePoint. See following documentation for details. We did change the API structure slightly between preview and GA, but the basics have remained the same with MSGraphClient usage and no reason for any manual access token handling.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph